# How to recursively replace a string in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

The title tells it all: I am wondering how can I replace a string in all files in sub-folders of a folder.

Comment: In the standard replace-all dialog you can choose the "where" option, in which you can indicate the main folder. See [the official docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html)

Comment: The problem is I don't see `where` among the options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Unofficial Docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html#searching) you can do this via the "Search and Replace" option, which is invoked by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or in the menu `Find > Find In Files`) and will pop up something that looks like this on the bottom:

[image]

From there, you can enter a folder name, or select the `...` for other criteria you can add (inclusions, exclusions, etc).